# Getting ERR_ABORTED trying to load https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403

My firebase web app has started giving this error today morning. I swear it was working fine last night. "GET https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client net::ERR_ABORTED 403" error. I have simplified it down to this page that still giving me the error. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
  <head>
    <title>Debug</title>
    <!-- Favicon-->
    </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in my case, I figured out what was going on. I had put a couple of custom devices to test my app on different screen dimensions. I had also put in a user agent string for each (didn't really need it). That was the problem. Removing the user agent string from these new custom devices fixed the issue.